# Python simulation of a company's

Tags: python, random, module, simulation

I have an assignment where I have to use Python code to simulate a company's hourly average maximum customer volume. The homework prompt says to import the random module and use the random.random() method. My issue is that I don't know what to put into the function itself. Here's the code I have so far:

```
import random

#Function to calculate the average maximum of customers per hour

def ave_max_calc(C, H, D):

    **HELP**


print('Hello, welcome to my average maximum hourly customer volume calculator!')

C = int(input('Give the number of customers per day: '))
H = int(input('Give the number of business hours per day: '))
D = int(input('Give the number of days to simulate: '))

print('The average maximum hourly customer volume is: ', ave_max_calc(C,H, D))
```

Comment: Finally, a student who at least attempted to do something. Try reading this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: The first thing to do is clearly and unambiguously define your terms, the calculations will follow from those definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum hourly customer volume is a rate so you should simulate this with a poisson distribution. You can create a poisson distribution like this:

```
import numpy as np
rate =  float(C)/H
customers = np.random.poisson(rate, D*H)
```

Documentation for the poisson distribution can be found here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.poisson.html

When you say average maximum do you mean the average of the maximum customer rate for each day?